# Execute immediate not returning expected result to search a string in entire table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to write a PLSQL block which would display column names of a specified table if it contains a specified lookup text.

*Please find the code below for my procedure :*

[image]

Upon execution I am not getting any results. Used it on sample HR schema. In the below example I am trying to find out the columns containing Steven.

```
set serveroutput on;

exec col_name_string('EMPLOYEES','STEVEN')
```

;

I think my code has some issue but still not throwing any runtime exceptions.

Comment: Because you are using a bind variable, you are executing the following query select count(1) from EMPLOYEES where UPPER( :col ) = UPPER(:search_value) and not select count(1) from EMPLOYEES where UPPER( COLUMN_NAME ) = UPPER(:search_value) as you are expecting. I mean, you are comparing 2 variables and not a column to a variable. Instead of using UPPER(:col), you need to create dynamically the SQL text as already shown. There is no errors because you are executing a good query but not the desired one. It was really interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code works; note line #14 - concatenate column name, don't bind it.

(I prefer creating a statement (in `l_str`) so that I can see it (using dbms_output.put_line) and - if it is OK - execute it).

```
SQL> create or replace procedure col_name_string (tab_name    in varchar2,
  2                                               search_val  in varchar2)
  3  as
  4     cnt    number;
  5     l_str  varchar2 (200);
  6  begin
  7     for i in (select column_name
  8                 from user_tab_columns
  9                where table_name = upper (tab_name))
 10     loop
 11        l_str :=
 12              'select count(*) from '
 13           || tab_name
 14           || ' where upper(' || i.column_name || ') = upper(:search_val)';
 15        execute immediate l_str into cnt using search_val;
 16        if cnt > 0 then
 17           dbms_output.put_line('Column : ' || i.column_name || ' contains the string');
 18        end if;
 19     end loop;
 20  end;
 21  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec col_name_string('EMP', 'KING');
Column : ENAME contains the string

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

(By the way, you'd rather post code itself, not image of it).

Comment: I don't have reputation to upvote but thanks to you for your answer.

Comment: @avkrish - you can still [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem.